# What is the origin of the name “Fizzle Bomber” in Predestination?

Tags: predestination

Much of the film Predestination centers around a character called the “Fizzle Bomber”. Why is this character named this way? They may have mentioned it in the film but I cannot recall.

I have my own theory but it’s not really based on anything.

> The timeline of the main character seems to pop into 
>  existence and fizzle out in its own temporal loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a reference to their inability to set a *working* nuclear weapon. It ['fizzled'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzle_(nuclear_explosion)) and merely destroyed ten city blocks.

> Everybody knows now why the Fizzle War of 1963 fizzled. The bomb with New York's number on it didn't go off, a hundred other things didn't go as planned---all arranged by the likes of me.
>
> <sub><sup>—All You Zombies—</sup></sub>

In the film we see a newspaper article at the start of the film. The caption reads

> The FBI have today dubbed the recent spate of bombings the work of the "fizzle" bomber. The name comes from the type of device used in the detonation of the explosions that have rocked the US over the past 4 years.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea the word “fizzle” had a definition that directly related to nuclear weapons. Makes sense now.